# returning a single row using case

Tags: mysql

I have a field name ParcelID, a field name ShapeID and Quantity.
ParcelID is a foreign key, ShapeID contains the type of the same and Quantity is the amount of each ShapeID.

ParcelID can have more then one shape -> that means more then one line.

for example:

```
**ParcelID    ShapeID  Quantity**
1           Square       3
1           Triangle     7
1           Circle       6
```

I need a query that returns **a single row**, check the ShapeID and present the Quantity of those Fields : Square_Shape, Triangle_Shape, Circle_Shape.

final result:

```
**ParcelID  Square_Shape, Triangle_Shape, Circle_Shape.**
    1           3            7                 6
```

This is what i tried to far -> but no success:

```
SELECT ParcelID,ShapeID,Quantity
case when ShapeID = 'Square' then Quantity end as Square_Shape,
case when ShapeID = 'Triangle' then Quantity end as Triangle_Shape,
case when ShapeID = 'Circle' then Quantity end as Circle_Shape,

FROM sql_stock a
```

Answer (score 1):

You query is close.  Mostly you just a `group by` and aggregation functions:

```
SELECT ss.ParcelID,
       sum(case when ShapeID = 'Square' then Quantity end) as Square_Shape,
       sum(case when ShapeID = 'Triangle' then Quantity end) as Triangle_Shape,
       sum(case when ShapeID = 'Circle' then Quantity end) as Circle_Shape
FROM sql_stock ss join
     sql_history sh
     on ss.ParcelID = sh.ParcelID
GROUP BY ss.ParcelID;
```

You should use table aliases whenever you refer to a column.  I do not know if `ShapeId` and `Quantity` are coming from the stock table or the history table.

Also, if you want `0` to appear instead of `NULL` when there are no values, then add `else 0` to each of the `case` clauses.

EDIT:

The OP seems to have changed the original query to remove the history table.  The query would then be:

```
SELECT ss.ParcelID,
       sum(case when ShapeID = 'Square' then Quantity end) as Square_Shape,
       sum(case when ShapeID = 'Triangle' then Quantity end) as Triangle_Shape,
       sum(case when ShapeID = 'Circle' then Quantity end) as Circle_Shape
FROM sql_stock s
GROUP BY ss.ParcelID;
```

Comment: GROUP BY ParcelID is not working.
Yes, its presenting only one row but (and its a big but) some fields are missing information.

Comment: @user3162308 . . . I have revised the query since your comment.  I noticed some other errors in your original query.  Is it still not working?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  ParcelID,
  SUM(IF(ShapeID='Square',Quantity,0)) AS Square_Shape,
  SUM(IF(ShapeID='Triangle',Quantity,0)) AS Triangle_Shape,
  SUM(IF(ShapeID='Circle',Quantity,0)) AS Circle_Shape
FROM sql_stock
GROUP BY ParcelID
```

might be quite robust against missing or duplicate values

Answer (score 0):

Join your table with itself:

```
select t0.ParcelId, t1.Quantity as Square_Shape, t2.Quantity as TriangleShape, t3.Quantity as CircleShape  
from     
sql_stock t0
LEFT JOIN sql_stock t1 ON (t0.ParcelId = t1.ParcelId and t1.ShapeId = 'Square')
LEFT JOIN sql_stock t2 ON (t0.ParcelId = t2.ParcelId and t2.ShapeId = 'Triangle')
LEFT JOIN sql_stock t3 ON (t0.ParcelId = t3.ParcelId and t3.ShapeId = 'Circle')
group by t0.ParcelId, Square_Shape, TriangleShape, CircleShape;
```